# Node.js child_process issuewhile running in VS code

Tags: node.js

Below is the ERROR I am getting when I run following 2 lines of code

RUNNING IN VS CODE

ONLY 2 FOLLOWING LINES cause this trouble pls help me get started!!!!!!!!!
const cp = require("child_process");
cp.execSync("calc");

status: 127,
signal: null,
output: [
null,
Buffer(0) [Uint8Array] [],
Buffer(33) [Uint8Array] [
47,  98, 105, 110,  47, 115, 104,  58,
32,  99,  97, 108,  99,  58,  32,  99,
111, 109, 109,  97, 110, 100,  32, 110,
111, 116,  32, 102, 111, 117, 110, 100,
10
]
],
pid: 19417,
stdout: Buffer(0) [Uint8Array] [],
stderr: Buffer(33) [Uint8Array] [
47,  98, 105, 110,  47, 115, 104,  58,
32,  99,  97, 108,  99,  58,  32,  99,
111, 109, 109,  97, 110, 100,  32, 110,
111, 116,  32, 102, 111, 117, 110, 100,
10
]
}

Answer (score 0):

Check if `calc` is installed and can be found. 127 indicates that the program is not found.

Comment: But doesn’t calc, code and other stuff come inside child_process?? If not how to install calc ?

Comment: any ideas on how to solve this issue?????